# The input could only input number, how can I make it to also input string?

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree

How can one make the input to not only able to input number but also word? I tried changing the int with char[20] but that just made the program run continuously without stop. I'm still a newbie and looking for advice. Also, int x, c = 1, z; is confusing, why does the int have an equal value to 1? My thanks for anyone that would help.

```
struct node*insert(struct node*r, int x)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
            r = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            r->info = x;
            r->left = r->right = NULL;
            return r;
    }
    else if (x < r->info)
            r->left = insert(r->left, x);
    else if (x > r->info)
            r->right = insert(r->right, x);
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    int x, c = 1, z;
    int element;
    char ch;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1. Insert an element");
        printf("\n2. Search for an element");
        printf("\n3. Delete an element");
        printf("\n4. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter the item:");
                scanf("%d", &z);
                root = insert(root,z);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nEnter element to be searched:  ");
                scanf("%d", &element);
                search(root, element);
                if(LOC != NULL)
                    printf("\n%d Found in Binary Search Tree !!\n",element);
                else
                    printf("\nIt is not present in Binary Search Tree\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nEnter the info to be deleted:");
                scanf("%d", &z);
                root = del(root, z);
                break;            
            case 4:
                printf("\nExiting...");
                return;
            default:
                printf("Enter a valid choice: ");
    }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "why does the int have an equal value to 1". I take it this is not your code? That being the case you cannot assume that random code from the Internet/friend is going to be good code. `c=1` initialises the variable to `1` but there is no need to do so as the variable will be overwritten by `scanf`. Unless `scanf` fails but that is another problem with the code as it does not do error checking.

Comment: Don't _describe_ your code that doesn't work but _show_ it. Read this [ask] and this: [mcve]. Then [edit] your question.

Comment: If you are working with string data instead of integer you also need to change the comparison conditions like `x < r->info` and use `strcmp`.